# Regex: Exclude numbers when matching hashtags

Tags: regex

I have the following regex `/#(\w+)/g` which I am using to identify hashtags in a video description. This works however it also picks up numbered lists, i.e., `#2`. How can I exclude these while still detecting hashtags?

Here is a more detailed example of what I want to include and exclude:
https://regex101.com/r/PGsAfh/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
#\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*
```

It basically means that after the `#`, you can have any word character you like `\w*`, but there's gotta be a letter `[a-zA-Z]` somewhere. I have used `*` to allow the letter to appear at the start and end of the hashtag, and I have put `\w*` on both sides to allow numbers to be at the start and end of the hashtag.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGsAfh/6)